# iOS iPhone mapview with slide-up scrollview - How to set up?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am struggling with how to set up the following view arrangement. Not sure what viewcontrollers I should use. Should I use a container view (I'm only supporting iOS6+)?

I have a screen that contains a mapview (and view controller) that is working great. I want to add a view to this screen that slides up from the bottom to partially cover the mapview. This subview will be a scrollview and will have a small handle that is visible even when closed that a user can drag up to open or down to close. When this drawer view is open, the user can "page" left and right through a list of objects and the map will update accordingly.

I don't need any help with the map view or scroll view individually, only how the generate this screen with the multiple views.

Everything I have done thus far is via Interface Builder.

Thanks!

Comment: If you do this it will intervene with iOS 7 control center. I wouldn't do that.

Comment: I'm not really tied to how the drawer slide is initiated, or that it even animates. I really just want to know, given that I have a full-view mapview and controller working correctly, how do I create a scrollview subview that displays on top of it? Does this sub-scrollview need it's own view controller?

Comment: I ended up just using the same view controller to control both the mapView and the scrollView since they're pretty tightly tied together. Created a xib and subclassed UIView with a custom view to repeat in my scrollView. This seems to be working well.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a empty xib (UIViewController) and add this Xib file as subview of the main view. Next add a gesture recognizer to the main view (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html), on the right gesture slide the subview up (http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation).